# kde corner actions - how does it work

Tags: kde, kde5, plasma5

There are hot corners in `kde`. My issue is that i had thought that when i go to the corner with the mouse, the action is executed, but this happens only about 25% of cases. Mostly when I move the mouse into the corner, nothing happens. The `system settings` says:

"To trigger an action push your mouse cursor against the edge of the screen in the action's direction."

Unfortunately, I do not even understand the sentence: What does it mean to push the mouse? (do I literally put the mouse on the screen and push on the corner???) What is the direction of the action?

So, my question is, what is the mysterious "spell" to make the corner action happen 100% times when I want it to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It says push the mouse **cursor**, not push the mouse. You need to move the mouse *cursor* towards the edge of the screen, or towards the hot corner. You do have to be fairly accurate, if you're a bit off the corner then it may not activate, or if you move it really slowly it won't activate, so there's no way to guarantee 100% success.